# ORA-04021 on recreating a Materialized View

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

WE are needing to re-create a materialized view as the query behind it has slightly changed.   However, this view is used so frequently, that any time we try, regardless of day or night, we get ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object.

Yes, we could shut down the listener and stop all the incoming connections, but for some reason management does not want to do that as it will affect the entire site.

My question is:  If I would create a new MV with a new name, and then create a public synonym pointing to that new MV, would the object owner itself use the synonym?  Or because the schema owner owners the object, it will not use the synonym.

Thought we could create a temporary MV and reference it via the synonym, then correct the actual one, and re-point the synonym.

Or any other possibilities?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to repeatedly recreate (`drop ... create materialized view ...`) your materialized view at all. Simply invoke `dbms_mview.refresh` on your existing view to repopulate it with new data. Ensure you are using an atomic refresh (`atomic_refresh=>TRUE`) so no truncate is needed. It shouldn't require locking the object.

If you *did* end up swapping two mviews, which is sometimes done in order to use non-atomic (truncate vs delete) refreshes in a busy environment, you would not be able to create a private synonym with the same name as the mview under the same owner. They are both objects and objects must be uniquely named within schemas. You would need to rename your mviews something else that your code isn't referencing.

Lastly, if it's both very large *and* very busy and an atomic refresh isn't acceptable for performance reasons, consider either a fast refresh (log-based) or, even better, writing your own refresh logic in a procedure that uses a `MERGE` on a normal table to surgically add/modify/delete rows at the individual row level based on what's changed instead of replacing all the data every time. As long as you aren't using query rewrite, this is sometimes preferrable to actual mviews.

Comment: The underlying query behind the MV has changed slightly, so we need to re-create it.   That is where the dilemma is.   So, was thinking if we create a new public synonym and point it to a new MV (MV1).  Wait a bit for everything to release locks on the existing MV.   Then correct the query behind the existing MV, and then re-create the public synonym pointing it to the existing MV.     Question is:  Will the object owner use the public synonym, or not because they are the owner of the MV.

Comment: @LandonStatis, The object owner will use their own object before they resolve to a public synonym. As I said in my answer, if you want to do the rocking synonyms method, you will need to rename your mviews something different than they are today. Also consider the merge approach. You can create a normal view and replace that normal view with a new definition each time, then call the procedure to merge the view results into your main table surgically. Or better, just dynamically build the SQL for the merge each time with new logic and avoid dropping/creating objects altogether.

Comment: @LandonStatis, you can also simply use atomic `dbms_mview.refresh` where the mview is defined as `select * from view` and `view` is a normal view that you change out each time then invoke the refresh. That way you are dropping an object nobody is using and it won't block. But I provided various other methods because dropping/recreating objects is usually not ideal in Oracle because of the dictionary changes it causes. It reverberates through a lot of things (invalidates cursors, holds various locks, could cause "object not found" errors, and a dozen other complexities in the wrong scenarios).

Comment: Paul:  Agreed, the SELECT * FROM view as the MV definition is a good idea.   Still need to get exclusive access to that MV to do that.   But I think that is a good approach.

Comment: @LandonStatis, you don't need exclusive access to the MV segment to swap out the view it selects from. It's the code that has the dependency, not the heap segment, and your users are using the heap.